# "heart function" or "heart's function"

Tags: possessives, genitive-construction

What's the correct [genitive construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitive_construction) of heart and function?

Should it be "**heart's** function" or "heart function"?

For instance:

> "The heart function is to supply blood to whole body."

or

> "The "**heart's** function" is to supply blood to whole body."

By googleing I found both choices, and that's why I'm not sure about it. Please, it would be very useful if you explain your answer, because I find my self in such situation very often about other words as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it existed, "heart function" would be either a type of function (perhaps meaning the "main function") or it could be a medical term, describing some specific property of the heart (Cardiac arrest is a sudden loss of heart function).  Either way, "Heart function" is not what you mean here.

You could say "The function of the heart", which gives the clue that the genitive is the right form. You would say "The heart's function..."  However consider rephrasing

> The heart supplies blood to the whole body.  (It's shorter, there is no need for the word function or a genitive and avoids the "function/purpose" ambiguity)

Comment: So badically both fofms are correct depend on contexts? (While in mine I can use both)